# How can I prevent a window from automatically maximising in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, 16.04, window-manager, window

The following animation demonstrates how I am unable to prevent a window from automatically maximising in Ubuntu 16.04 Unity upon opening.

[image: GIF animation]

Comment: only one specific window or you want to make it work for any window ?

Comment: Most windows behave correctly. However, in general any window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComizConfig Settings Manager has a "Place Windows" plugin where you can configure where newly-opened windows should be placed. Below is screenshot example of my setup for Google Chrome placement.

[image]

If that doesn't work, here's alternative solution. The script below runs continuously and prevents maximizing of the window in focus.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
#
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com
# Date: Oct 27, 2016
# Purpose: prevents x11 windows form maximizing
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/842317/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
from __future__ import print_function
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gio
import subprocess
import signal
import time


def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ reusable function for running shell commands"""
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout


def main():
    """ defines entry point of the program """
    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
    while True:
        active_window = screen.get_active_window()
        active_xid = str(active_window.get_xid())
        wm_state = run_cmd(
            ['xprop', '-root', '-notype', '-id', active_xid, '_NET_WM_STATE'])
        if ('_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT' in wm_state and
                '_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ' in wm_state):
            active_window.unmaximize()
            active_window.process_all_updates()
        time.sleep(0.25)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Great script, thank you! The Compiz approach did not work for me.